# Matrix exponential of a positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-exponential, positive-matrices

Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ real matrix with strictly positive elements, i.e. $M_{ij}>0, \forall 1\leq i,j\leq n$, and let $\lambda_1$ be its [Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) (i.e. the eigenvalue with largest magnitude, must be real and positive). Is the following inequality always correct?
$$[e^{M}]_{ij}\leq e^{\lambda_1}, \forall 1\leq i,j \leq n$$

It is easy to prove this when $M$ is symmetric, since when $M$ is symmetric, we have $\|M\|=\lambda_1$, therefore
$$[e^{M}]_{ij}\leq \|e^{M}\|\leq e^{\|M \|} = e^{\lambda_1}, \forall 1\leq i,j \leq n.$$
When $M$ is not symmetric, I checked several cases numerically and the answer seems to be true, but I don't know how to prove this. [The above proof fails because $\|M\|\neq \lambda_1$ when $M$ is not symmetric.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true.

*Suppose the claim was true:*
In particular, consider positive stochastic matrix $M$  and
$\Sigma:= \begin{bmatrix}\sigma_{1}& \mathbf 0^T\\ \mathbf 0 &\mathbf I_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} $   with  $\sigma_1 \gt 1$

$e^M$  is a positive matrix and has Perron Root $e$ thus

$\sigma_1\cdot\text{positive constant} =  \big[\Sigma e^M \Sigma^{-1}\big]_{1,2} = \big[e^{\Sigma M\Sigma^{-1}}\big]_{1,2}  \leq e$
but the upper bound is fixed while the lower bound may be made arbitrarily large by selecting large enough $\sigma_1$-- *which is a contradiction*.

working backwards, the counter example is
$M':= \Sigma M\Sigma^{-1}$
with sufficiently large $\sigma_1$